# How to get Angular Pre-compilation code，templateUrl's code

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I only want the code before compiling, instead of getting the compiled code through this.elementRef.nativeElement

I can get innerHTML through this.elementRef.nativeElement, but not what I want because I want to write the code in the editor.

```
enter code here
<nz-layout class="inner-layout">
  <nz-content class="container" #container (dragover)="dragover_handler($event)"
    (dragenter)="dragenter_handler($event)" (drop)="drop_handler($event)">
    <!-- 拖拽组件到这里 -->
    <drag-grid></drag-grid>
  </nz-content>
</nz-layout>
```

I want get The above code
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Your Angular code will be transpiled and compiled into html/javascript when it's built.

Check the link below for more info. 
https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01

Comment: But I want get compiled before code,because I need pre code ,and I will copy code